# Is there a way to access subversion repository from the web within corporate environment?

Tags: svn

I am in corporate environment which doesn't allow any internet access except http / https. So is there a way to access subversion repository from the web like a website which does offer this kind of service for free if possible (I mean not just download but also update the repo).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. You just need to give the URL of the repository. For example:

```
svn checkout http://somecompany.com/repos/aproject/trunk
```

As for finding free hosting, I suggest you google for `free subversion hosting`.